# Why is it faster to reallocate a buffer than to reset it?

Tags: c#, performance, buffer

While refactoring some old code, I decided to do some pointless premature optimization and to reutilize a buffer instead of reallocating it each time.
Much to my surprise, I discovered that it is incredibly slower.

Reproduction:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = (int)1e4;
        const int size = 100 * 1024;

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
        {
            buffer = new byte[size];
        }
        var reallocMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        var rewriteMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine($"Reallocating: {reallocMs} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"Rewriting: {rewriteMs} ms");

        Console.WriteLine($"Rewrite / reallocate = {(double)rewriteMs / (double)reallocMs}");
    }
```

When built in `Release`, rewriting every byte is ~8 times slower than to reallocate a new buffer. In `Debug` it drops to almost 50 times slower!

How is this possible? I expected that having a fixed buffer would have improved the performance, but it's obviously not the case.

What am I missing here?

**P.S:** And by the way, `Array.Clear()` is consistently even *slower* than the for loop, althought its performance is independent of the build configuration.

Comment: You're asking why doing a single memory operation is significantly faster than doing many thousands of them?

Comment: Well, if you phrase it like that... Let's say that I was suprised that the overhead of continuously finding a new free area, reserving that, and creating thousands of objects for the garbage collector was actually faster than finding a single area once and resetting its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you write to an array, it could throw an exception. So on every single write in the loop implementation, there is a bounds check on the index. That can be optimized away when first initializing a known range of memory.